# Excel Bug - Filtering causes screen to stop updating properly and breaks menus and dialogue boxes

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, office365

Strange one here that I can't seem to work out, so any help is appreciated.

This bug is primarily noticed on 1 computer, on 1 spreadsheet more than any other by a significant amount, but it is not exclusive to this 1 user or spreadsheet. However, since it's most common by far with this user/computer/spreadsheet combination it's easiest to focus on this combination.

When a filter is applied or cleared, the spreadsheet appears to lock up but it doesn't become unresponsive - just unusable.  The filter doesn't apply visually, and nothing can be clicked on.  The File menu will open as blank, and dialogue boxes pop up but are also blank.

This Dialogue Box doesn't show anything, but it should be asking if I want to save because I've clicked to close the workbook. If you click where Yes, No, or Cancel *should* be, or press the keyboard shortcut, it will Save, Not Save, or Cancel, depending on what you press.

[image: Dialogue Box]

Within the spreadsheet, the formula bar doesn't change wherever you click. But if you click on it, a white box will appear in a random location but you can't affect it.

[image: Random White Box]

Filters can be clicked, but not in the place that they're actually supposed to be. In this example I clicked where the circle is which opened a filter box, but the filter content shown was from way over in column F. I can't find anywhere to click to show the filter for this particular filter in column B

[image: Not my Filter]

When I click the File menu, the whole page shows as blank with some artefacts from the spreadsheet. Pressing Esc clears this screen and returns to the broken version of the spreadsheet:

[image: File Menu]

Some further information or things I've tried:

- This is not a Macro-Enabled workbook
- It can happen regardless of whether it's the only sheet that's open
- If it happens, then any open workbooks are also affected in the exact same way
- The computer has multiple screen
- There are no touch-enabled screens, just standard keyboard/mouse interaction
- So far, when investigating the problem for the user on a remote connection, I have **NEVER** seen the problem happen. However, if the problem has already happened then I inherit the existing problem on my remote session until I close Excel
- Because of the above I've changed the computer from an NVIDIA graphics card to on-board, but no improvement
- All computers are always updated with the latest Windows 10 updates
- All computers are using Microsoft 365 Office Desktop versions
- I've completely reinstalled Windows and Office on the most-affected computer
- Nothing shows up in the Event Viewer
- The file which causes the problems most often is stored on a shared Network drive, accessed via a Mapped drive letter (Z:)

I hope this is enough for someone to be able to suggest what might be happening and how to fix it, this is everything relevant I could think of

Comment: are there any third party add-ins active ?

Comment: [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-spreadsheet-flashing-white-screen-when-doing/0262f045-e1b0-4ec0-8e62-ff3fd16a2bc7) suggests (1) to try and see if safe mode changes anything, (2) that it could be an issue of the default printer driver. Other thing that comes to mind: what happens if you change the view to something else, or zoom in/out ?

Comment: If the folder `C:\Windows\Minidump` contains `.dmp` files with matching timestamps, please zip up a few and post them online for us to examine.

Comment: @1NN No third party apps. There is 1 now (Nitro PDF)  but this problem predates this addition. Windows and Excel were reinstalled and it happened within an hour of using it for the first time.

Comment: It looks like a corruption of the display buffer. What you could try is to copy all data to a fresh excel file, to make sure there's no junk data creating it.

Comment: Is it possible to check for a CPU or network usage spikes at the moment of the freeze? Is the display driver updated, and is there a correspondence between display&network adapters and the computers where this happens?

Comment: @1NN Thanks, I'll give it a go

Comment: @harrymc The drivers are updated. Originally it had a fully updated Nvidea card, but I removed that and the problem still happens with the onboard graphics

Comment: Do you see some common hardware to the computers having the problem ?

Comment: All computers are Dell Optiplex, using multiple displays on Display Port. Since posting this originally, the problem has only happened on one computer (mentioned as the most affected) and happens several times in succession, and is then fine for a few days. This computer is also the one that uses these particular sheets more than any other, by a significant amount

Comment: If it is similar to what I experience, it seems sometimes when I have excel on my secondary monitor (which is most of the time) I do get some issues with menu items not displaying. I can "resolve" this by moving the window to my primary monitor.

Comment: Does this happen when booting in Safe mode with Network (if it's possible for the user to work in this mode)?